# Array "expression must have a constant"

Tags: arrays, c++-cli

I need to convert C# code to C++ although not once did not move C++, combines only from different parts of what and how something looks and then somehow it works. I now mainly have a problem with an array that gives me an error as the topic.

```
public: 
    int arrimg( Bitmap^ image)
    {
        const int w = image->Width;
        const int h = image->Height;
        const int z = 3;
        int dtab[w][h][z];
        for (int x = 0; x < image->Width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < image->Height; y++)
            {
                dtab[x][ y][ 0] = image->GetPixel(x, y).R;
                dtab[x][ y][ 1] = image->GetPixel(x, y).G;
                dtab[x][ y][ 2] = image->GetPixel(x, y).B;
            }
        }
        return dtab;
    }
```

The error still pops up on me "in" and "h" and do not know how to fix it. The second matter if I give rigidly number for "a" and "h" is also "dtab" crashes mistake, "Rerturn type does not match the function type.

Comment: `int arrimg( Bitmap^ image)` not c++. Maybe c++-cli.

Comment: 1. array sizes should be compile time constants
2. you're returning an int [] [] []  not an int

Comment: @drescherjm jup, that's C++/CLI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change two lines to use a multi-dimensional [`cli::array`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts4c4dw6.aspx)

```
cli::array<int, 3>^ arrimg(System::Drawing::Bitmap^ image)
...
auto dtab = gcnew cli::array<int, 3>(w, h, z);
```

Note the `cli::array<int, 3>^` syntax instead of `int[,,]` in C#; and the use of `gcnew` instead of `new`.  For completeness, the full code is:

```
cli::array<int, 3>^ arrimg(System::Drawing::Bitmap^ image)
{
    const int w = image->Width;
    const int h = image->Height;
    const int z = 3;
    auto dtab = gcnew cli::array<int, 3>(w, h, z);
    for (int x = 0; x<image->Width; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y<image->Height; y++)
        {
            dtab[x, y, 0] = image->GetPixel(x, y).R;
            dtab[x, y, 1] = image->GetPixel(x, y).G;
            dtab[x, y, 2] = image->GetPixel(x, y).B;
        }
    }
    return dtab;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler gives you a clear message of what's wrong: you can't have a local array of variable size. You must allocate dtab explicitly with new or use something like std::vector. Furthermore, the return type is wrong, as your code tries to return a 3D array of int, but the return type is declared to be a single int.

Comment: A mild annoyance here "The compiler gives you a clear message" is not a useful thing to say when the OP has already quoted the message and indicated that they don't understand what it is trying to tell them.   This is particularly relevant here when the OP is obviously not a native English speaker.  I'm not trying to start a flame war or anything, just suggesting that you consider the circumstances before saying something like this in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::vector` instead of Variable Length Arrays (VLA).

For example:

```
std::vector< std::vector< std::vector<int> > > dtab;
```

Or allocate the array dynamically:

```
int * dtab = new int [w * h * z];
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ (and apparently not C++/CLI (which you are using) either) doesn't support [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array).

While `w` and `h` in your code might be constant, they are only constant in the meaning that they can not be modified. They are not *compile-time* constants, which is required for array dimensions.

The variable `z` on the other *is* a compile-time constant, because its value can be set by the compiler, it's not depending on other run-time variables or values.

If you want to stick with a pure C++ solution, it would be to use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

Which compiler are you using?

This below line of code

```
int dtab[w][h][z];
```

will not work in Visual Studio, but `gcc` and `clang` is generous about it. For example, the code

```
int i;
cin>>i;
int arr[i]
```

generates the same error as the error you're getting in you question, but compiles with other compilers and works perfectly

The reason is that visual studio expects C++ arrays to be `constant`, and if they are not constant you need to create memory using an array.